# Create a context to a local database using a context class from a WCF data service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, windows-phone-7

I have created a helloworld app. On the server-side there is a model class generated by Entity Framework and a WCF data service. In my WP7 app I added a reference to this service. It allowed me to do something like that:

```
DataServiceCollection<Blogs> blogs;
BlogContext svc; // this class was generated with the model class by EF
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9430/BlogService.svc/");
svc = new BlogContext(uri);
blogs = new DataServiceCollection<Blogs>(svc);
```

This simply grabs the blogs. Now I'd like to put those blogs into a local database using the same classes (Blog, BlogContext) I used above. It would save me fixing 2 different classes in case the model changes. How can I do this? Please be precise, I'm new to WP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Having a model on the server
- Having another model on the client
- Try to map one model's object to another mode's object, say using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

i.e.:

```
void Save(ServerBlog sb)
{
    using (var db = new LocalContext())
    {
        var clientBlog = new ClientBlog
        {
            Text = db.Text
            // or the same using AutoMapper
        };
        db.Blogs.Add(clientBlog):
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend not trying to persist the same classes you receive from the WCF service and instead map them to the model on the phone.

If you're planning on using [SQLCE](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database%28SQL-CE%29-Introduction) you'll need to create your model and mark them up to tell EF how they map to your database.  Trying to do that to the stuff WCF creates might be possible with partial classes but it sounds like it would be a pain.

[SQL Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) is excellent and can do all the work for you once your database model is complete.  I generally use a combination of Server Explorer and SQL Compact Toolbox when working with SQL CE on the phone.

update:
With portable class libraries you could share the WCF DTO library between the projects but I still wouldn't try and mark those up with EF attributes.

Comment: @abatishchev thanks for the edit but EF attributes might be confusing as EF isn't supported on the phone.

Comment: I see, lets ask for a clarification by OP to determine what does he use on the phone.

Comment: Maybe the term 'DataContext' is more appropriate.  "Each property of the TimelineItem is decorated with a Column attribute, which tells the
DataContext that the property is stored in a column by the same name."